# How do I make jenkins to execute particular file

Tags: linux, jenkins, continuous-integration, devops, job-scheduling

I have been trying to schedule a job in jenkins . My script resides in a  folder /root/test and here im sharing the location of it .

```
[root@fahost test]# ls

jenkins_bkp  README.md  t1.sh  t2.sh

[root@fahost test]# pwd

/root/test

[root@fahost test]#
```

But when I mention the same path in Jenkins it's showing me the following result:

Console Output

> Started by user Jenkis Test
>
> Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/bkp_db
>
> [bkp_db] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins3680779476651257016.sh
>
> - cd /root/test
>
> /tmp/jenkins3680779476651257016.sh: line 2: cd: /root/test: Not a
>   directory
>
> Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
>
> Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Does Jenkins have access to `/root/test` ? Most probably it does not, because it runs as jenkins user, but `/root` is accessible only by `root`.

Answer (score -1):

In the configure of you job go to **Build** section select **Execute Shell**, then type the below.

`cd /root/test;./<file_name>.sh`